# Is the category Ord well-pointed?

Tags: category-theory

I'm trying to determine what a terminal object for the category **Ord** would look like. Right now I'm thinking that a terminal object in **Ord** is just a set containing a single element $a$ with the relation $a \leq a$. Denote this object by $O$.

Claim: If $A \in$ **Ord**, then we have a unique morphism $f : A \to O$ given by $f(a') = a$ for all $a' \in A$. I think this deduction means that every singleton set with an empty relation is also a terminal object in **Ord**.

If the claim is true how can I show it?

Given that the claim is true, I'm having trouble thinking of a global element $f : O \to K$ for some $K \in$ **Ord**, since $f$ must preserve the structure of $K$.

Comment: If $\mathbf{Ord}$ is the category of partial orders and monotone maps, then a singleton with the empty relation is not an object in the category; partial orders still satisfy reflexivity.

Comment: Can you clarify your definition of the category $\mathbf{Ord}$?

Answer (score 0):

You are right about the terminal object. Why is there a unique morphism $A \to O$? A fortiori, there is a unique map $A \to O$ (since $O$ is a terminal object in $\mathbf{Set}$, if you want). It suffices to verify that this unique map is order-preserving, which is indeed the case: $x \leq y \implies a \leq a$ is a trivial implication.

There cannot be a nonempty initial object: if $O$ were a nonempty initial object, consider the disjoint union $K = O \sqcup O$: it admits at least $2$ order-preserving maps from $O$.

Instead, the initial object is the empty set with empty order-relation.

Comment: I don't think the OP asks about an initial object. Rather they seem to be asking what points $1\to K$ look like.